# How do you a depends_on an async command (and make it trigger async as well) on buildkite?

Tags: asynchronous, buildkite

I have an async trigger step in buildkite (e.g. I don't want it to block the rest of the pipeline). However, I want the next command to only execute if the async step passes. How can I configure this in buildkite?

Reading through the buildkite documentation not sure if this is possible. I don't see an async attribute for anything but a trigger step -- but I just want to execute a command.

https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/

Answer (score 0):

> I want the next command to only execute if the async step passes.

That sounds like what a non-async trigger does? i.e. Run the triggered build and, on success, run the next command step. Perhaps you need to remove `async: true` from the trigger step and have a `wait` step in between?